# How to write Unit Test Case for below javascript function using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to write Unit Test Case for below javascript function using Jasmine?

```js
function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per jasmine documentation, jasmine contains two things describe and specs.

> The describe function is for grouping related specs, typically each
>   test file has one at the top level. The string parameter is for naming
>   the collection of specs, and will be concatenated with specs to make a
>   spec's full name. This aids in finding specs in a large suite. If you
>   name them well, your specs read as full sentences in traditional BDD
>   style.
>
> Specs are defined by calling the global Jasmine function it, which,
>   like describe takes a string and a function. The string is the title
>   of the spec and the function is the spec, or test. A spec contains one
>   or more expectations that test the state of the code. An expectation
>   in Jasmine is an assertion that is either true or false. A spec with
>   all true expectations is a passing spec. A spec with one or more false
>   expectations is a failing spec.

Read more [here](https://jasmine.github.io/)

You can do something like this:

```js
function GetURLParameter(sParam) {   
    var sPageURL = "email=someone@example.com"; //replace it with your
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
// specs code
describe("check for url", function() {
  //defining it should be something
  it("should be defined", function() {
    expect(GetURLParameter).toBeDefined();
  });
  
  it("should run", function() {
    expect(GetURLParameter('email')).toEqual("someone@example.com");
  });
  
 

});

var NOT_IMPLEMENTED = undefined;

// load jasmine htmlReporter
(function() {
  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
  env.execute();
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
```